# How to implement file navigation? (meaning directory browsing on the side)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directory-browsing

What I mean is basically what's shown in the picture below (picture is fictitious).

[image]

I'm creating a website using HTML, Angular, Bootstrap.

I need a way to show the directories / navigate files on the computer on the page.

I am stuck:
- I am not sure how to describe this, I have searched google for "file navigation", "directory navigation" and so forth with no success, maybe I am calling it by the wrong name?
- I have never implemented this sort of thing before.

I would greatly appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction on how to go about doing this, since it seems like quite a simple and standard thing to do.

Goals (something very basic):
- be able to navigate through directories
- show the folders and files on the webpage
- be able to add a "onclick" function when click on a file (like opening the file on the same page on another section - these will only be .txt files)

- The files / folders that I need to display are on the computer itself, and not on some server.

Comment: Directory browsing is a configuration setting on your web server such as IIS and Apache.  It is usually turned of for security reason.  If you are not hosting your own, you may not have access to it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what files and directories are on the server, first you'll need to get the server to report what they are. You've listed a bunch of client side technologies, but you'll need server side code to do this (because the directory you want to list is on the server).

Most HTTP servers will generate the listing for you (e.g. with [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_autoindex.html)). You could also use the server side language of your choice to generate a listing.

Since you are using Angular, you'll need to make an HTTP request to the URL that returns the listing you want, parse it to extract the data you want, and then insert that data into a view.

Comment: I get what you are saying in terms of the files being server side, but if i'm referring to the folders on the computer itself? That would be client side right?. This is for a uni project, and it's a web-based app, but it will take the files/folders that are on the computer itself.

Comment: @ImZyzzBrah — The screenshot you posted was in the style of an Apache mod_autoindex listing which implies you were talking about the server. If you want to generate a listing of files on the computer running the browser (instead of the computer running the server) then you are out of luck. The browser sandbox does not allow JavaScript to explore the visitor's computer for security reasons.

Comment: That would make sense actually yes, that could be kinda dangerous to allow JS to explore the visitor's computer.